# Вычитание времени из текущей

Tags: sql

есть таблица SALES, есть столбец ORDER_DATE с датой, необходимо сделать запрос на вычитание из текущей даты ORDER_DATE

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  some (
  somedate DATE
);


INSERT INTO some VALUES("2020-11-30");

SELECT CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ) - somedate FROM some;
```

есть функция `GETDATE()` которая возвращает дату и время но с помощу  `CAST( GETDATE() AS Date )` мы приводим её к типу `DATE` смотря что у вас за `sql` вожможно на вашей есть другая функция для возврата даты но ето уже вам решать